# The [ninja] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, meta-tags

There were only 5 questions with the tag [ninja](/questions/tagged/ninja):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658440/android-rss-parsing-from-joomla
- [How to search across a directory of files in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190844/how-to-search-across-a-directory-of-files-in-vim)
- [PHP RegEx: How to Stripe Whitespace Between Two Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474951/php-regex-how-to-stripe-whitespace-between-two-strings)
- [Remove decimal from ordered <ol> list via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153019/remove-decimal-from-ordered-ol-list-via-css)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830559/what-should-every-asp-net-programmer-know

<sub>(text parsing seems to be a very ninja thing to do)</sub>

I removed the tag from most of the above because it struck me as a [meta-tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), but the last question ([What should every ASP.Net programmer know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830559/what-should-every-asp-net-programmer-know)) is locked.

How can it be removed, and can (should?) we blacklist [ninja](/questions/tagged/ninja) as a tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locked posts can be edited by any moderator. The general plan is you can always **flag the post for moderator attention**, and explain that the tag needs removal. You can flag a locked post. Failing that, a Meta post *is* an option if there's a lot, but in general flagging is sufficient.

Blacklisting [ninja](/questions/tagged/ninja) seems not too necessary. With a lack of precedent, it's unlikely that it will spring up again. Blacklisting is more for things which we *expect* continual problems with.